why is $f \in \Gamma(V)?$
The following theorem is from Fulton's book see page no $21$
Fulton proposition $2$
$\Gamma(V)=\bigcap_{p \in V}\mathcal O_p(V)$
It is written that

If $f \in \bigcap_{p \in V}\mathcal O_p(V)$, $V(J_f)=\emptyset$ so $1 \in J_f $(Nullstellensatz) i,e $1.f= f \in \Gamma(V)$

My confusion:  why is $f \in \Gamma(V)?$
My thinking :$V(J_f)=\emptyset \implies J_f=K[x_1,x_2,....,x_n]$ and $\Gamma(V)=\frac{k[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]}{I(V)}$  but $I(V)=I(\emptyset)=K[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$
Therefore $\Gamma(V)=\frac{k[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]}{I(V)}=\frac{k[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]}{k[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]}=1$
This lead to contradiction  because $f$ is nonconstant

Why $I(V)=I(\emptyset)$?

@azif00 $I(V)=I(V(J_f))=I(\emptyset)$

$V$ is an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb A^n$, $V(J_f)$ is the set ${P \in \mathbb A^n : F(P)=0 \text{ for all } F \in J_f}$, where $J_f = {G \in k[X_1,\dots,X_n] : \overline Gf \in \Gamma(V)}$.

If I've understood your question, I think it follows from the definition of $J_f$? Since $J_f = \{G\in k[x_1...x_n] \mid Gf \in \Gamma(V)\}$ and it is established $1\in J_f$ so $1\cdot f \in \Gamma(V)$?
Also, $V \neq V(J_f)$.
